# Fatal Error building the llvm source code in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, clang, llvm, llvm-clang, ninja

I am trying to build LLVM source code on Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried versions 4.0.1, 4.0.0 and 3.9.0 with sources from [here](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html). I have also tried using the source from svn as shown in several tutorials.

Here is the error I get :

```
[1480/1747] Linking CXX executable bin/clang-3.9
FAILED: : && /usr/bin/c++   -fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Werror=date-time -std=c++11 -fno-common -Woverloaded-virtual -fno-strict-aliasing -g  -Wl,-allow-shlib-undefined   -Wl,--export-dynamic tools/clang/tools/driver/CMakeFiles/clang.dir/driver.cpp.o tools/clang/tools/driver/CMakeFiles/clang.dir/cc1_main.cpp.o tools/clang/tools/driver/CMakeFiles/clang.dir/cc1as_main.cpp.o  -o bin/clang-3.9  lib/libLLVMAArch64CodeGen.a lib/libLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMAArch64AsmParser.a lib/libLLVMAArch64Desc.a lib/libLLVMAArch64Info.a lib/libLLVMAArch64Disassembler.a lib/libLLVMAMDGPUCodeGen.a lib/libLLVMAMDGPUAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMAMDGPUAsmParser.a lib/libLLVMAMDGPUDesc.a lib/libLLVMAMDGPUInfo.a lib/libLLVMAMDGPUDisassembler.a lib/libLLVMARMCodeGen.a lib/libLLVMARMAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMARMAsmParser.a lib/libLLVMARMDesc.a lib/libLLVMARMInfo.a lib/libLLVMARMDisassembler.a lib/libLLVMBPFCodeGen.a lib/libLLVMBPFAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMBPFDesc.a lib/libLLVMBPFInfo.a lib/libLLVMHexagonCodeGen.a lib/libLLVMHexagonAsmParser.a lib/libLLVMHexagonDesc.a lib/libLLVMHexagonInfo.a lib/libLLVMHexagonDisassembler.a lib/libLLVMMipsCodeGen.a lib/libLLVMMipsAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMMipsAsmParser.a lib/libLLVMMipsDesc.a lib/libLLVMMipsInfo.a lib/libLLVMMipsDisassembler.a lib/libLLVMMSP430CodeGen.a lib/libLLVMMSP430AsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMMSP430Desc.a lib/libLLVMMSP430Info.a lib/libLLVMNVPTXCodeGen.a lib/libLLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMNVPTXDesc.a lib/libLLVMNVPTXInfo.a lib/libLLVMPowerPCCodeGen.a lib/libLLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMPowerPCAsmParser.a lib/libLLVMPowerPCDesc.a lib/libLLVMPowerPCInfo.a lib/libLLVMPowerPCDisassembler.a lib/libLLVMSparcCodeGen.a lib/libLLVMSparcAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMSparcAsmParser.a lib/libLLVMSparcDesc.a lib/libLLVMSparcInfo.a lib/libLLVMSparcDisassembler.a lib/libLLVMSystemZCodeGen.a lib/libLLVMSystemZAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMSystemZAsmParser.a lib/libLLVMSystemZDesc.a lib/libLLVMSystemZInfo.a lib/libLLVMSystemZDisassembler.a lib/libLLVMX86CodeGen.a lib/libLLVMX86AsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMX86AsmParser.a lib/libLLVMX86Desc.a lib/libLLVMX86Info.a lib/libLLVMX86Disassembler.a lib/libLLVMXCoreCodeGen.a lib/libLLVMXCoreAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMXCoreDesc.a lib/libLLVMXCoreInfo.a lib/libLLVMXCoreDisassembler.a lib/libLLVMAnalysis.a lib/libLLVMCodeGen.a lib/libLLVMCore.a lib/libLLVMipo.a lib/libLLVMInstCombine.a lib/libLLVMInstrumentation.a lib/libLLVMMC.a lib/libLLVMMCParser.a lib/libLLVMObjCARCOpts.a lib/libLLVMOption.a lib/libLLVMScalarOpts.a lib/libLLVMSupport.a lib/libLLVMTransformUtils.a lib/libLLVMVectorize.a -lpthread lib/libclangBasic.a lib/libclangCodeGen.a lib/libclangDriver.a lib/libclangFrontend.a lib/libclangFrontendTool.a lib/libPolly.a lib/libLLVMGlobalISel.a lib/libLLVMAArch64Desc.a lib/libLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMAArch64Info.a lib/libLLVMAArch64Utils.a lib/libLLVMAMDGPUDesc.a lib/libLLVMAMDGPUAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMAMDGPUInfo.a lib/libLLVMAMDGPUUtils.a lib/libLLVMARMDesc.a lib/libLLVMARMAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMARMInfo.a lib/libLLVMBPFAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMHexagonDesc.a lib/libLLVMHexagonInfo.a lib/libLLVMMipsAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMMipsInfo.a lib/libLLVMMSP430AsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMPowerPCInfo.a lib/libLLVMSparcAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMSparcInfo.a lib/libLLVMSystemZDesc.a lib/libLLVMSystemZAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMSystemZInfo.a lib/libLLVMX86AsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMX86Utils.a lib/libLLVMX86Info.a lib/libLLVMXCoreAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMAsmPrinter.a lib/libLLVMDebugInfoCodeView.a lib/libLLVMSelectionDAG.a lib/libLLVMCodeGen.a lib/libLLVMXCoreInfo.a lib/libLLVMMCDisassembler.a lib/libclangCodeGen.a lib/libLLVMipo.a lib/libLLVMVectorize.a lib/libLLVMInstrumentation.a lib/libLLVMObjCARCOpts.a lib/libLLVMScalarOpts.a lib/libLLVMInstCombine.a lib/libLLVMTarget.a lib/libLLVMBitWriter.a lib/libLLVMIRReader.a lib/libLLVMAsmParser.a lib/libLLVMLinker.a lib/libLLVMTransformUtils.a lib/libLLVMAnalysis.a lib/libLLVMCoverage.a lib/libLLVMObject.a lib/libclangRewriteFrontend.a lib/libclangARCMigrate.a lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend.a lib/libclangFrontend.a lib/libclangDriver.a lib/libLLVMOption.a lib/libLLVMProfileData.a lib/libclangParse.a lib/libLLVMMCParser.a lib/libclangSerialization.a lib/libLLVMBitReader.a lib/libclangSema.a lib/libclangEdit.a lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a lib/libclangStaticAnalyzerCore.a lib/libclangAnalysis.a lib/libclangAST.a lib/libclangRewrite.a lib/libclangLex.a lib/libclangBasic.a lib/libLLVMCore.a lib/libLLVMMC.a lib/libLLVMSupport.a -lrt -ldl -ltinfo -lpthread -lz -lm lib/libPollyISL.a -Wl,-rpath,"\$ORIGIN/../lib" && :
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
```

This is a recurring error in all three versions I tried, so there's probably some step I am missing or some other problem too.

These are my steps:

1. Download llvm.
2. Download clang, lld and polly and put in llvm/tools.
3. Download compiler-rt, openmp, libcxx, libcxxabi and test-suite and put in llvm/projects
4. Run `cmake -G Ninja -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=On ..`
5. Run `ninja -j4`

I don't know how to remove this error and dont have any experience with LLVM. Please explain the reason for the error too.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336515/9027283) answer may be helpful in your case too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59436978/992406 see me answer here.

Answer (score 8):

This may be caused by the linking step using too much memory. On my system there was enough swap space enabled which made the system practically unusable because the swap space was on a HDD. Otherwise the Linux kernel will kill some processes according to a heuristic that probably involves going after the biggest memory user, which could explain your problem (ld is killed).

If you have something around 8 GB of RAM it may be possible to finish with at most one link job in parallel. By default llvm is built with static libraries which causes the linking to take excessive amounts of memory (AFAIR due to debug info). Then usually several large executables will be linked in parallel by ninja and your system will run out of memory.

Try to add `-DLLVM_PARALLEL_LINK_JOBS=1` to your cmake invocation.

There is also an option to build shared libraries which should alleviate this problem, I think it is `-DLLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB=true`.

For more info on CMake options see: http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html

I think that using the gold linker also helps because it is somewhat more efficient than the default linker. It is enabled by passing -DLLVM_USE_LINKER=gold to cmake.

Finally, the release build does not contain the debug info, which takes up a lot of the memory, so it should take less memory to build.

Update:
I recently came across [this article](http://www.productive-cpp.com/improving-cpp-builds-with-split-dwarf/), that describes how to use split dwarf to speed up compiles with LLVM as an example. This helps the memory consumption of the linker by separating the debug information from the object files being linked.
For LLVM split dwarf is enabled by passing the option `-DLLVM_USE_SPLIT_DWARF=ON` to cmake.

Comment: I checked online for more info, and people say creating more swap space should help too. I have 5.4G of swap space and 8G RAM. Is that enough?

Comment: When I last tried on my laptop, I could build with 8 GB of RAM, but I restricted the jobs to 1 and was using the gold linker. Back then I did not know about selectively setting the number of link jobs, which is faster, as the compilation can happen in parallel.

Comment: My experience with swapping while building LLVM was that my system became completely unuseable. I had to turn it off after a few hours. So I do not recommend relying only on swap space for this. The build, if it ever finishes may take days.

Comment: How do I use the gold linker?

Comment: Try adding -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS='-fuse-ld=/usr/bin/gold' to the cmake invocation. I cannot check the cmake invocation right now but with -fuse-ld=linker you tell g++ to use "linker" as linker. Cmake will use the compiler as linker to ensure that the runtime is linked properly and it will then call the linker with the right arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, I'm using SSD hard so there is no need for swapspace. This command works for me -DLLVM_USE_LINKER=gold