# LLVM 6 Trunk Build on Ubuntu 16.04 not building lld

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I am building LLVM 6 on Ubuntu 16.04. I want `lld` too. But no matter what I do, `lld` doesn't build/install.

Followed the following instruction from [here](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#overview). *Still sifting through first and second :)*

1. Read the documentation.
2. Read the documentation.
3. Remember that you were warned twice about reading the documentation.

   In particular, the relative paths specified are important.
4. Checkout LLVM:

   ```
   cd where-you-want-llvm-to-live
   svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
   ```
5. Checkout Clang:

   ```
   cd where-you-want-llvm-to-live
   cd llvm/tools
   svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk clang
   ```
6. Checkout Extra Clang Tools [Optional]:

   ```
   cd where-you-want-llvm-to-live
   cd llvm/tools/clang/tools
   svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/clang-tools-extra/trunk extra
   ```
7. Checkout LLD linker [Optional]:

   ```
   cd where-you-want-llvm-to-live
   cd llvm/tools
   svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lld/trunk lld
   ```

Didn't download the other optional packages. Since `svn` download was not working properly (`svn: E000104: Error running context: Connection reset by peer`), I downloaded respective `zip` for [LLVM](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm), [Clang](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang), [clang-extra](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang-tools-extra) and [lld](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/lld) from their github mirrors. Since, I didn't use `svn` some renaming of the folders had to be done (for e.g. `clang-tools-extra-master` to just `extra`).

Then execute the following, after `cd`ing into the parent folder of the `llvm` source folder,

```
$ mkdir build; cd build
$ cmake ../llvm
$ make
```

After waiting for +8 hours, I get all the programs (`clang`, `lli`, `llc` etc.) except `lld`. I am expecting it to appear in the folder `build/bin`.

I have also tried the option `cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=llvm/tools/lld ../llvm`. (The form `-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=lld` doesn't work and I found [this](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2017-June/114021.html) place discussing about the same ENABLE issue.)

I have already tried things with some tweaking three times. Since it takes so much time to compile, I decided to take your help.

A separate issue: While building, linking phase takes 12 GB RAM + 8.8 GB swap space on my laptop!! Does LLVM building really require >20 GB of ram ? (I had closed all other foreground apps, especially `firefox`)

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Regarding the RAM use of the linking phase: this is due to debug information and static linking, see this answer for different approaches to mitigate the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/44808601

Comment: @PaulR thanks for the link. Will give it a try whenever I build next. I forgot to mention that I used `make -j 2`, hence parallel linking could be another culprit as the link indicates.

Comment: Now that I think about it, my guess would be that LLVM_PARALLEL_LINK_JOBS mentioned in the post will only work with ninja. But ninja works nicely otherwise, so you could give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think that the `LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS` option is useful if you use a "flat" source directory layout. In your case, if you performed the checkouts as you wrote, then it's not of much use.

Moreover, what @PaulR wrote about using `ninja` is a very good suggestion. It's faster and very useful when restarting builds and it spawns as many separate compilation jobs concurrently as it can depending on the `nproc` without having to specify it explicitly.

For faster build and shorter link times, I'd also suggest enabling a shared libs enabled build using the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` option.

Some general good advice can be found [here](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2015-04/slides/eurollvm-2015-build.pdf), which can be summarized as:

1. use `clang` to build `clang` (a bootstrapped or second-stage build).
2. use the `gold` linker instead `ld` for faster linking times.
3. prefer a build producing shared libraries.

You can skip point 1 for now (although you could install an initial `llvm/clang` from the system package manager)

Lastly, you could limit the compilation for the specific target backend you currently require using the `LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD` option.

I've built `trunk` recently (including `lld`) with this `cmake` configuration:

```
CC=gcc CXX=g++ \
cmake -G Ninja \
  -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=On \
  -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=On \

  -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=On \
  -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86" \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_SPHINX=Off \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_THREADS=On \
  -DLLVM_INSTALL_UTILS=On \

  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
  [path-to-source-root-dir]
```

You can add the following flags if you need to build `libcxx`:

```
[...]
-DLLVM_ENABLE_LIBCXX=On \
-DLIBCXX_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS=On \
-DLIBCXX_ENABLE_RTTI=On \
[...]
```

For a bootstrapped build using another `llvm/clang` and `libc++` you can augment the above command as (having that `clang` in your `$PATH` environment variable):

```
LLVM_TOOLCHAIN_LIB_DIR=$(llvm-config --libdir)

LD_FLAGS=""
LD_FLAGS="${LD_FLAGS} -Wl,-L ${LLVM_TOOLCHAIN_LIB_DIR}"
LD_FLAGS="${LD_FLAGS} -Wl,-rpath-link ${LLVM_TOOLCHAIN_LIB_DIR}"
LD_FLAGS="${LD_FLAGS} -lc++ -lc++abi"

CXX_FLAGS=""
CXX_FLAGS="${CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++ -pthread"

CC=clang CXX=clang++ \
cmake -G Ninja \
  -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=On \
  -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=On \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_LIBCXX=On \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=On \
  -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86" \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_SPHINX=Off \
  -DLLVM_ENABLE_THREADS=On \
  -DLLVM_INSTALL_UTILS=On \
  -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS=On \
  -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_RTTI=On \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="${CXX_FLAGS}" \
  -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="${LD_FLAGS}" \
  -DCMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS="${LD_FLAGS}" \
  -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="${LD_FLAGS}" \
  -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0056=NEW \
  -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0058=NEW \
  [path-to-source-root-dir]
```

Moreover, another relevant SO question of interest can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304919/building-and-using-a-pure-llvm-toolchain-for-c-on-linux).

As you wrote, reading the documentation, experimenting and reading the documentation again is the way to go.

Comment: I tried the first cmake configration you gave (without the flags for libcxx) in a fresh build folder, but I get linker error continuously. Though I tried running `ninja` countless times (since each invocation did link some files) it doesn't move beyond [2/200] mark. The error is: `/home/codeman/mydata/local/packages-live/clang-llvm6/llvm/include/llvm/Analysis/DominanceFrontier.h:122: undefined reference to 'llvm::DominanceFrontierBase<llvm::BasicBlock, false>::DominanceFrontierBase()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: things break sometimes when you work on trunk. are you willing to try with `LLVM` 5.0.0. I'll try to find the git refs of when I've built it last.

Comment: The command worked on LLVM 5.0.0 release, with clang, clang-extra and lld !! With ninja the whole thing got built in 2 hours! (will compare it with `make -j 4` soon). @compor you were right LLVM Trunk must be buggy at this point. I followed the same steps and got `lld` where it needed it to be. Thanks!

Comment: The difference between `ninja` and `make` will be most palpable when you modify and rebuild. Last built `LLVM`trunk (6.0.0) that worked for me is "a694e228c261eec9940ea99cf60de8da4453bf8e" (if still interested), but that's a moving target since there are other projects as well. Anyhow, if you absolutely need trunk, play around with different checkouts.