# Using shared object (.so) by command opt in llvm

Tags: llvm

I am a llvm beginner. I run the command:

```
../llvm-6.0.0.src/build/bin/opt -load=./test.so -Hello < main.bc
```

according to the tutorial but got the error:

```
opt: CommandLine Error: Option 'use-dbg-addr' registered more than once!
LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options
```

I googled again and again, and got nothing about this error.

Answer (score 4):

You need a LLVM build with shared libraries enabled, which corresponds to `cmake` options `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=On`. You can check what type of LLVM you have installed by either checking its `lib` directory or executing:

```
llvm-config --shared-mode
```

This should report `shared`; anything else will require you to recompile.

Comment: Thanks for your help! After runing "llvm-config --shared-mode" I got "static", so I have to compile llvm again?

Comment: yeah, I'm afraid so. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696773/llvm-6-trunk-build-on-ubuntu-16-04-not-building-lld/47729443#47729443) thread could help a bit

Comment: hmm, I recompile the llvm as your advice, and now "llvm-config -shared-mode" says "shared", but now get another problem:" opt: CommandLine Error: Option 'o' registered more than once!". So what's wrong with this error?

Comment: are you sure you have the right `opt` in your `$PATH`? What does `which opt` say?

Comment: unless you're also defining a `-o` option in your plugin too? that is already taken by `opt` itself

Comment: Thanks for reply. "which opt" says "/usr/local/bin/opt", and there is no difference between "which opt" and "llvm/build/bin/opt", compared by vimdiff. And I just ran the same command in the question, but got such error.

Comment: I found that cmake couldn't recognize "add_llvm_loadable_module". I just compile llvm as the llvm.org says.

Comment: oh ok, you hadn't said so; let's see how that goes

Comment: I hava used cmake options `-DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=ON` `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` to solve this problem in llvm-15.0.7